# How to get current get_post_types name?

Tags: custom-post-types

How can I get the current custom post type name and echo it on a page?

Answer (score 43):

You'll need the post object somehow, or, alternatively the queried object on post type archives. On a singular page you might do:

```
$post = get_queried_object();
$postType = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post));
if ($postType) {
    echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name);
}
```

Or in the loop:

```
$postType = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
if ($postType) {
    echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name);
}
```

In post type archives:

```
$postType = get_queried_object();
echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name);
```

All of these will give you the singular name of the post type that was registered in `register_post_type`'s `labels` key.

Comment: Can you help me here. I use the following code now: http://snippi.com/s/wookr64 With this code I want to call only the current posttypes on the page. Now it doesn’t work correctly. What does I wrong?

Comment: @Casper I think what you will need to do, go and sit down, and reconstruct your previous question. It is still totally unclear what you want. Why did [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27137675/1908141) not work. Explain with examples and template names exactly what you want. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

To get the name of the current post type, use the following code inside the loop.

```
$post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
```

or display the post type name using printf function.

```
printf( __( 'The post type is: %s', 'textdomain' ), get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `get_post_type()` retrieves the post type of the **current post** or of a given post. More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/).